# .Net signing with strong name key file and SHA256

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, sha1, sha256, sha

We currently sign our assemblies using an SHA1 strong name key file in Visual Studio using the .Net 4.0 framework.  The main reason we use strong naming is the ability to use "InternalsVisibleTo" in our assemblies.  Since SHA1 is now deprecated I believe we should be switching to SHA256.

I have attempted to generate and use SHA256 as the strong name key file in Visual Studio in .Net 4.0 but it cannot generate one, although I can create an SHA256 through .Net 4.5 and then assign that to my .Net 4.0 project and it appears to accept it when I use the "Sign the assembly" feature in Visual Studio.

My question is does .Net 4.0 have the ability to correctly utilize the SHA256 strong name file generated in .Net 4.5?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: .NET 4.5+ is a binary replacement for 4.0. If you install 4.5 on a machine with 4.0, it gets replaced. Given that, do you *really* need to keep targeting 4.0 in your projects? In any case, how you sing an assembly isn't that important. TLS 1.1/1.2 though is only implemented in 4.5.2. *That* is a critical difference, especially now that many sites and providers drop support for anything less than 1.2

Comment: Can't really migrate to 4.5 at this point as we still have users who are on XP.  But a good thought.

Comment: Then don't experiment. XP is more deprecated than SHA1 anyway. Even if the signed assembly works on a test machine (because the .NET 4.5 runtime has replaced the 4.0 runtime) it may not work on an XP machine, where 4.5 can't be installed. In any case, the docs show that [Enhanced Strong Naming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh415055(v=vs.110).aspx) does more than just use SHA-2

Comment: That's a good point about maybe not even working on XP anyway.  I will setup a test and do some research on Enhanced Strong Naming.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options to create Personal Exchange File (*.pfx),

1. Using Makecert

   "makecert.exe" -n "CN=Local" - r -pe -a sha256 -len 2048 -cy authority -e 
   03/03/2017 -sv Local.pvk Local.cer

   "pvk2pfx.exe" -pvk Local.pvk -spc Local.cer -pfx Local.pfx -po 
   MyPassword -sy 24
2. Using OpenSSL

   openssl.exe req -x509 -nodes -sha256 -days 3650 -subj "/CN=Local" -newkey 
   rsa:2048 -keyout Local.key -out Local.crt

   openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -in Local.crt -inkey Local.key -CSP "Microsoft 
   Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" -out Local.pfx

The OpenSSL is more reliable way of doing this.